# MySQL: You have an error in your SQL syntax; near ''' at line 5

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running this query in a `*.php` file and receive the following error:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'Employees.txt'
INTO TABLE employees
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
```

Response:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 5

I am running mysql version 5.6.17 and php version 5.5.12
Text file simple has:

```
"000";"Employee Name"
```

for each line.
The query works fine when used within phpmyadmin or via mysql console.
PHP Code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
###### db ##########
$db_username = 'user';
$db_password = 'pass';
$db_name = 'dbase';
$db_host = 'localhost';
################

$query="
LOAD DATA INFILE 'Employees.txt'
INTO TABLE employees
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
";
echo $query.'<br>';

//Connect to DB
    $connecDB = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name)
    or die('could not connect to database');
    echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

mysqli_query($connecDB,$query) or die(strftime('%c')." ".mysqli_error($connecDB));
mysqli_close();
echo strftime('%c')." ok!";

?>
```

Comment: Did you double escape those backslashes when building the query string in PHP?

Comment: @developerwjk If I omit the ESCAPED BY '\\' it will bring in the first line fine, but after that it doesn't populate any of the other employee id's.

Comment: @marcus-adams the example is pulled directly from the php query.

Comment: Have you tried: `ESCAPED BY '\'`? Also if you are have problems where it only get the first line, maybe your lime terminator is wrong, it could be `\r\n` or `\n`

Comment: @dan08 I tried `ESCAPED BY '\'` , same error, when I tried '\\\' or '\\\\' I received Access denied for user.

Comment: put cuted file here first 10 rows for example

Comment: this query and the sample line seems OK. have you brought all the informations to have a right clue?

Comment: The only guess I have: you did some mistake when convert this SQL query string to php query string, so could you provide the php code? or confirm that you have the same error mmessage when phphMyAdmin ? or direct mysql command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$query="
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Employees.txt'
INTO TABLE employees
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '\\\"'
ESCAPED BY '\\\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r'
";
echo $query.'<br>';
```

Comment: I received Access denied for user. Appears to be when too many backslahes are used.

Comment: there is NO *too many slashes* that just brings your query to the query you declared from the begining. you just never looked at your `echo` attentively

Comment: Echoed query: `LOAD DATA INFILE 'Employees.txt' INTO TABLE employees FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'` No idea why the access denied error when the credentials never changed and work fine with test query.

Comment: When I try to use the LOCAL parm I receive `ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`

Comment: It works, had to add the \n in order for it to pull the employee id in after the first row.

Comment: Ok. Good luck with your project then! :-)